# Without using 3rd party libraries is URLSession necessary in order to obtain remote data?

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurlsession

Typically I use AlamoFire but have been testing out URLSession.  I tried retrieving data with

> try? Data(contentsOf: URL)

and was able to get the data properly.  Is there a benefit to using URLSession compared to this method?  This way seems cleaner but maybe I'm missing something.  Here is my full function which works properly:

```
class UrlSessionNetworkManager: NSObject {

  static let sharedManager = UrlSessionNetworkManager()

      func parseJSONFromData(urlExtension:String)-> [String : AnyObject]?
      {

        let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string:"\(baseURL)\(urlExtension)")!)

        if let data = jsonData {

          do {
            let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String : AnyObject]

            return jsonDictionary

          } catch let error as NSError {

            print("error processing json data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
          }
        }

        return nil
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note - obtaining remote data is a completely separate discussion from doing something with the obtained data. So your question really has nothing to do with JSON or parsing JSON. It's all about obtaining remote data. You should remove all irrelevant code from your question and keep the focus on the one relevant task.

Comment: I think simply reading the docs for `URLSession` will answer your question. It tells you of all of the benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several critical points:

- Using NSData to obtain the contents of non-local URLs is considered unsupported behavior, and may break at any time.
- Using NSData to obtain non-local URLs happens synchronously, which means the thread in question cannot make progress until the request completes (potentially for *minutes*).
- iOS kills processes that block for more than 30 seconds, so if you use NSData to retrieve a URL on your main thread, then on a slow network, your app will get killed repeatedly.

So basically, the answer is "Do not under any circumstances do what you're thinking about doing."